# How can I use Django with MySQL in MAMP stack?

Tags: python, django, mysql, mamp

I have difficulty especially in installing MySQLdb module (MySQL-python-1.2.3c1), to connect to the MySQL in MAMP stack.
I've done a number of things such as copying the mysql include directory and library (including plugin) from a fresh installation of mysql (version 5.1.47) to the one inside MAMP (version 5.1.37).

Now, the MySQLdb module build and install doesnt give me error.

The error happens when I'm calling 'import MySQLdb' from python shell (version 2.6).

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>

  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/_mysql.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/_mysql.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/rhenru/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3c1-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg-tmp/_mysql.so, 2): Symbol not found: _mysql_affected_rows
  Referenced from: /Users/rhenru/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3c1-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg-tmp/_mysql.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/rhenru/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3c1-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg-tmp/_mysql.so
```

Any idea, what else do I need to do to make it works?

Thanks a bunch,
Robert

=========
Add the system response after using virtualenv as suggested by Hank Gay below...

```
(MyDjangoProject)MyMacPro:MyDjangoProject rhenru$ which python
/Users/rhenru/Workspace/django/MyDjangoProject/bin/python
```

After I run python in virtualenv, importing MySQLdb:

```
>>> import MySQLdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>

  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/_mysql.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/_mysql.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/rhenru/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3c1-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg-tmp/_mysql.so, 2): Symbol not found: _mysql_affected_rows
  Referenced from: /Users/rhenru/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3c1-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg-tmp/_mysql.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/rhenru/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3c1-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg-tmp/_mysql.so
```

import sys and sys.path

```
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.path
['', '/Users/rhenru/Workspace/django/MyDjangoProject/lib/python2.6/site-packages/distribute-0.6.10-py2.6.egg', '/Users/rhenru/Workspace/django/MyDjangoProject/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-0.7.1-py2.6.egg', '/Users/rhenru/Workspace/django/MyDjangoProject/lib/python26.zip', '/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/PyXML-0.8.4-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg', '/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pydot-1.0.2-py2.6.egg', '/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pyparsing-1.5.2-py2.6.egg', '/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/vobject-0.8.1c-py2.6.egg', '/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pytz-2010h-py2.6.egg', '/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3c1-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg', '/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/distribute-0.6.12-py2.6.egg', '/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pip-0.7.1-py2.6.egg', '/Users/rhenru/Workspace/django/MyDjangoProject/lib/python2.6', '/Users/rhenru/Workspace/django/MyDjangoProject/lib/python2.6/plat-darwin', '/Users/rhenru/Workspace/django/MyDjangoProject/lib/python2.6/plat-mac', '/Users/rhenru/Workspace/django/MyDjangoProject/lib/python2.6/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/Users/rhenru/Workspace/django/MyDjangoProject/Extras/lib/python', '/Users/rhenru/Workspace/django/MyDjangoProject/lib/python2.6/lib-tk', '/Users/rhenru/Workspace/django/MyDjangoProject/lib/python2.6/lib-old', '/Users/rhenru/Workspace/django/MyDjangoProject/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-darwin', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-tk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-mac', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/Users/rhenru/Workspace/django/MyDjangoProject/lib/python2.6/site-packages', '/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages', '/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/PIL', '/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg-info', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/wx-2.8-mac-unicode']
```

Answer (score 1):

How are you installing [MySQL-Python](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/)? I just tested in a fresh virtualenv and `pip install mysql-python` seems to have done the trick.

UPDATE:

[pip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) is sort of like a package manager for Python packages.

By default, `pip` installs to your current `site-packages` directory, which is on your `$PYTHONPATH`. This lets other libraries/applications (like Django) access it. `pip` also works well with [`virtualenv`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) (it should; Ian Bicking wrote them both), which is a nifty library that lets you sandbox an application. This is nice because it means you can try out new things without polluting (or even needing write access to) the global `site-packages` directory.

It probably seems like yak-shaving right now, but I'd say it's worth the effort to get up to speed on `pip` and `virtualenv` (you may also want to look into [`virtualenvwrapper`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenvwrapper), but we'll skip that for now; it's just sugar for `virtualenv`). It will lead to a *slightly* more complicated deployment scenario than putting everything in the global `site-packages`, but for development it's really no harder, and there are lots of good guides to deploying using a `virtualenv`.

I'd recommend something like the following:

1. `curl -0 http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py`
2. `python distribute_setup.py`
3. `easy_install pip`
4. `pip install virtualenv`
5. `virtualenv --distribute MyDjangoProject --no-site-packages`
6. `cd MyDjangoProject`
7. `source bin/activate` (this activates the sandbox that `virtualenv` created)
8. `pip install django mysql-python`

At this point, you should have a totally functional Django+MySQL install (if I missed any steps, just comment and I'll try to add it in). You can start your Django project like this: `django-admin.py startproject MyDjangoProject`. `cd` into your project's directory, edit your `settings.py` file to point to your MySQL database, and run the dev server to test it out like so: `./manage.py runserver` (you may need to `chmod u+x` your `manage.py` file). Voila! You should be able to access your site on `localhost:8000`. When you're done working on the project, you can just use `deactivate` to exit the `virtualenv` sandbox.

Try not to hold all this against Django: a lot of it is just best practices stuff for working with Python libraries. You could get by with a lot less, but this way it's more reproducible and you're less likely to accidentally mess up one of this project's dependencies when working on a different project.

Comment: Hi Hank, 
Thanks but I don't get you, what do you mean by MySQL-Python? If you are referring to the connector, that's what I'm trying to install right now.

And where do you run pip install mysql-python? what's the OS and is that a shell commmand?
I don't have that pip command, should I add it first?

Thanks,
Robert

Comment: Thanks Hank, I'm following your 8 steps. I got the MyDjangoProject with bin, include, and lib inside.
I'm trying to call bin/python and execute 'import MySQLdb' but I got the similar error (as what I pasted in my question).
Did I miss out something?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: What do you see when you execute `which python`? It should be showing you the python inside the `bin` subdirectory; if it's not, you probably need to `source bin/activate` and check again. Assuming it is, please fire up the REPL by typing `python` and then type `import MySQLdb` and paste in the exact output now. Also, please `import sys` and `print sys.path`, and past the output here as well.

Comment: Hi Hank, the which python has shown the path inside the project I created with virtualenv, however the python-mysql library is still referred at the same main python directory.
I pasted the output as part of my question above...
Thanks!

Comment: Hi Robert. I'm sorry—my instructions above were incomplete. I should have told you to use the `--no-site-packages` option when creating the virtualenv (I used `alias` to map `virtualenv` to `virtualenv --no-site-packages`, so I sometimes forget it's not the default). You could either uninstall the global version (I'd probably do this anyway, since it's not working) and/or create a new virtualenv using the `--no-site-packages` option. If you choose to uninstall `mysql-python`, you might be able to leverage `pip`: *outside* the virtualenv, use `sudo pip uninstall mysql-python`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and it turned out to be due to an errant configuration:
    export VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_32_BIT=yes
I can't recall what I had this enabled for (some package that required 32-bit), probably related to Google AppEngine. But Setting it to 'no' solved by issues.

Otherwise I just installed everything using homebrew and pip.